# SQL Server Reporting Service

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Recently I saw a presentation in which the reporting part of the software had a nice feature. When we hovered the mouse over the charts in the report, datailed information regarding that part of the chart appeared as a tooltip.

Is there such a feature in SQL Server reporing services 2005? If not, how can I add it?

Also can I make SSRS 2005 charts to look as beautifull as SSRS 2008? if not, is there a way to hava better colours in charts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that it might be possible with a third party charting product e.g. http://www.dundas.com/Components/Products/Chart/RS/Why/Benefits/Multiple.aspx but have never used one for RS so don't know that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS 2005 tooltip is possible only for the full chart, and not for particular bar in the chart. So the tooltip can be useful to show some title of the chart in SSRS 2005.
To get more from SSRS 2005 check [Get More Out of SQL Server Reporting Services Charts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SSRS 2005 doesnt have as many of the bells and whistles that you get with SSRS2008, the tooltips and good grphics etc for charts and graphs are only implemented as standard from 2008 as a result of Microsoft buying the rights to the Dundas software.

Answer (score 0):

There is Dundas charts and Nevron charts that you can use. Dundas charts was bought by Microsoft for inclusion in 2008 so what you get is very similar in capabilities, however I am not sure for how long they will be selling the product and no new updates will be coming to it.

Since charts in SSRS 2005 are rendered as images (true for dundas and nevron as well), there is very little support in terms of tooltips.